# What is the preferred method for formatting code?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

My primary question is

**What is the preferred method for formatting code?**

followed by

**Is the formatting help at odds with the preferred formatting method?**

The sidebar for the "Ask a question" interface currently looks like this:

[image: The first two bullets describe how to format code with fences. The sixth describes how to do it with spaces.]

Notice that "indent code by 4 spaces" is still there. However, you could be forgiven for not noticing it.

---

### Historical Context

When I first started asking questions on Stack Overflow, I believe the sidebar recommended something else for formatting code. My best guess is that it recommended something like `<pre>` tags:

```
You can still format code using tags that can't be used in the code itself!
Who knew?
```

So I actually don't remember exactly what was the method highlighted in the sidebar at the time. I just remember that the very first thing that happened after I made my first post was that someone edited the post to remove the recommended formatting method and indent the code four spaces. At the time, I was startled, to say the least. However, I got the hint and ever afterward used four spaces to indicate code.

I was startled because the community's preferred method of formatting code contradicted the formatting help. A problem that still seems to be happening today.

Today, I was curious about the new "Ask a question" interface, so I decided to have a look at it. I was startled to see this:

[image: First bullet says to format code with fences. There is no mention of using spaces.]

Why is the official Stack Overflow code formatting help at odds with the accepted conventions?

I am not requesting that backticks be supported. I am asking

- Which code formatting convention is preferred?
- If four spaces is preferred, why doesn't the documentation reflect this?
- If neither format is preferred, why are backticks more heavily emphasized in the help shown to new users and question askers?

I am not asking about `inline` backticks. I am asking about

````
```
backticks used to format code
```
````

versus

```
    spaces used to format code
```

Comment: In brief: happily, fenced code blocks actually work now. As for being the preferred method, I feel it makes sense, as they are less fiddly than the four spaces method.

Comment: The only thing it shows is that everyone forgets what the formatting help looked like years ago. If you were a new user to the site then, the help recommended using a formatting convention that every other user had to tell you to stop using. It was surreal.

Comment: @DavidCullen I don't think there is a strong preference either way; in any case, it doesn't seem to be a settled matter. Ctrl+K and the toolbar button still add four spaces. Relevant: [*Should we make the {} button add ``` instead of four spaces?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378924/2751851)

Comment: Did Stack Overflow ever support another method for indenting code? Something like `[code]` tags?

Comment: @David Yup, you can actually indent code in posts with `<pre> code </pre>` HTML tags. It's been supported (though not suggested) for as long as I remember, which extends back to about 2015. I know it works in posts, although I'm not sure about comments, so I'll give that a try: <pre> This is inside a pre-formatted block </pre> ... Looks like it didn't work, probably because HTML is deactivated in comments.

Comment: *...someone edited the post to remove the recommended formatting method and indent the code four spaces...* Assuming all of your code was properly formatted and did not cause any other issues with your post, they should not have done that. There are certain ways of formatting code that play nicer with other formatting (putting code in an unordered list for example) but there isn’t a preferred way that you’re supposed to use.

Comment: I have raised the issue of both ways of making code blocks showing up in that sidebar in [a separate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387779/2751851).

Comment: I don't know whether to laugh or cry. Why is "primarily opinion-based" a close reason on meta?

Comment: @David I say this is a case of something to laugh at. The POB close reason exists on Meta for posts that cannot have an objective answer (even though there are certain subjects where opinions do matter to the functionality of the site so they get through, but your's isn't like those): "...but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." However, you are explicitly asking for the preferred method, meaning one that's supported by references, not people's opinions as to which should be preferred.

Comment: In this case, the answer is "There isn't one, code fences or 4 spaces are both fine." The reason for showing one more obviously than the other is also possible to answer objectively, since the Stack Overflow employees who worked on it could answer and say why. So POB is not a valid reason to close your question, and you should laugh at it.

Comment: Does Stack Overflow the Company have a preference? I guess I should really ask that as a separate question, but this is as much fun as I can handle for now.

Comment: I've seen far more instances of people fubaring code fences than indenting. With code fences, I've seen them using the wrong quotes, and attempting to combine them with indenting which is more work to manually fix. Personally, I'd rather people use indenting and have code fences nixed altogether. I personally don't see any point to code fences.

Comment: Case and point: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57235714/3000206

Comment: @DavidCullen if SO themselves had a preference, wouldn't they have just enforced it and removed the alternative?

Comment: If you're using spaces it's a lot uglier and non-standard as you have to use some archaic SGML comment like `<!-- language: xxx -->` or `<!-- language-all: xxx -->` rather than communicating the information with a CommonMark info string. Moreover, it's less likely to be supported upstream with other tools (eg., Github, GitLab, BitBucket, etc). It's also more likely to cause problems with HTML serialization, and it's far more ugly to read as text. Generally, for the people that care the standard code-fence with info string provided by CommonMark (shown above) is a better option.

Comment: @BSMP "...someone edited the post to remove the recommended formatting method and indent the code four spaces..." this might be enticed by one SO/SE rule that I still fail to find useful: you must not make edits to other people's posts when you only change 1 character, even if this is the only edit needed to fix an error. In fact, SO advises users to find anything more to edit, like reformatting the post!

Comment: @IngoSteinke You're supposed to find something else to edit, but it's still supposed to be a good edit. More often than not, when I review a suggested edit where they only changed one or two characters and then did something random to satisfy the character limit, there was at least one other thing that needed fixing.

Answer (score 17):

Between fenced code blocks and indented code blocks, I don't think there is a strong preference either way (at least, not yet), so no one is going to be bothered by your choice on that. It is worth noting that both CTRL+K and the toolbar button still produce indented code blocks (for the feature request to change that, see [*Should we make the {} button add ``` instead of four spaces?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378924/2751851)).

> If neither format is preferred, why are backticks more heavily emphasized in the help shown to new users and question askers?

Presumably because they tend to be less fiddly than indented code blocks, not requiring changes to the Markdown lines with the code. Another advantage is that with fenced blocks you don't need an HTML comment to change the syntax highlighting.

(By the way, that the Ask a Question sidebar also says "indent code by 4 spaces" is probably a mere oversight.)

Answer (score 12):

TL;DR: Favor fenced code blocks. Like... always.

Might read like opinion, but there's rationale to it, too. On cursory look using either one (code fences or indentation) will have identical effects. So why even care?

I've been pondering about this for while now, and there are in fact differences, subtle, yet with surprising consequences. Code fences satisfy a lot more formatting needs than indentation can. And they are easier to use, too!

### Ergonomics

Code fences allow an author to copy-paste code, verbatim. No need to (artificially) indent the code in a code editor, just so that it shows up properly when translated to Markdown. This holds true when initially publishing a contribution, as well as when editing it, so translating a contribution into a format that's easier to edit is an improvement.

There's one unfortunate downside: Depending on the keyboard layout used, the backtick key can be a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) requiring additional key presses to enter an odd number of backtick characters. That's a one-time investment, though, and if you've written bash scripts in the past you probably don't even perceive it as an investment at all.

There's another ergonomic aspect: The web-based editor has a fairly narrow fixed width. Horizontal space is precious, and using up any of that will inevitably higher the chances of the editor breaking lines of code apart. Navigation suffers, both by keyboard and eye. Fenced code blocks do not use up any of that space for formatting, making it less likely to run into this usability issue.

### Syntax highlighting

Code fences allow for specifying a syntax highlighting hint ([info string](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#info-string)). Using indented code blocks one would need to drop out of Markdown down to HTML comments to specify what language the following (or all) code block should be rendered as.

````
```cpp
/* Some code */
````

is far more concise, obvious, and less cluttery than

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->

    /* Some code */
```

The latter isn't only more verbose, it's also creating a dependency on a particular Markdown renderer implementation. Stack Overflow [switched to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/205381), improving interoperability by agreeing on a common specification. Promoting the latter is leaving an opportunity on the table (see also [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark#comment1167195_348754)).

There seems to be a [popular opinion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387765/what-is-the-preferrred-method-for-formatting-code/409009#comment853500_409009) that *"a language indicator [were] redundant"*. This assumes that the heuristic used to detect languages works reliably ([it doesn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373056/1889329)), and will not change over time ([it has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/205381)). If you want to make sure that code renders as desired, and *continues* to render as desired over time and across different tools, a language tag is required.

CommonMark has a standard feature that suits itself for this purpose ([info string](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#info-string)). That feature is unavailable for [indented code blocks](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#indented-code-blocks).

### Vertical separation

Occasionally it is desirable to provide related, yet distinct portions of code. A C developer may want to post a header followed by its implementing compilation unit, e.g.

```c
/* source.h */
void foo();
```

```c
/* source.c */
void foo() {}
```

I'm not aware of a way to produce the identical rendered result in Markdown alone using indentation.

<sup>Nitpicker's Corner: It *is* possible to achieve it by placing an empty HTML comment between the two indented blocks, but this is rather a hack and is certainly not obvious to someone unfamiliar with the intricacies of Stack Overflow's Markdown rendering. The solution with code fences is much more obvious and intuitive.</sup>

---

### Recommendation

When authoring new contributions, prefer fenced code blocks with an info string over indented code blocks. It's the only syntax available in CommonMark that supports an author in conveying the desired syntax highlighting applied.

When performing or reviewing edits that change from indented code blocks to fenced code blocks, make sure the following requirements are met:

- Edits remove the (now) redundant spaces.
- Edits include a language tag.

Reviewers can choose the *"Improve Edit"* option to install those requirements when missing. Extra bonus if you apply vertical spacing as desired.

I will even go one step further and say that an edit that replaces an HTML-comment style language hint with a fenced code block plus info string is an improvement. It both improves interoperability and future-proofs a submission by making it resilient against changes in language detection heuristics.

Comment: I think the syntax highlighter takes tags into account when no language is provided, which should get it right 99% of the time. But I do agree with you. Fences are easier to type out, less prone to horizontal scrolling on long lines, don't require hacky-feeling comments, etc. Not worth editing a previously-fine post, though.

Comment: These advantages are irrelevant when it comes to editing a question that's already posted with correct syntax highlighting. Edits that only change from one to the other are, by definition, "no improvement whatsoever" (to how the post is displayed, because it doesn't change how the post is displayed). Unless one is officially marked as deprecated, that is, but even then, going around editing posts only to change that is probably not desirable. A language indicator is redundant (and should thus not specifically be edited in) when the syntax highlighting is correct due to the language tag.

Comment: I agree that fences are objectively better, but I also think the _only_ sensible edit policy is one that makes the fewest changes necessary to make a post intelligible. If the original post reads and parses correctly, don't mess with it. This is one reason I often reject edits that use garbage like Prettier to reformat someone's code: if indents are incorrect, fix that, but don't mess with their quote marks, use of spaces, etc. Try to preserve the original poster's voice and choices, even if they are bad, unless they prevent the community from engaging. "Do the least harm."

Comment: I am *strongly* of the opinion that one should not make edits which change a post from one valid representation to another, *just because the editor likes the other representation* or thinks it's "better". This applies to different Markdown representations, different dialects of English (e.g. American English vs. British English vs. ...), different [indenting styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style), etc. In particular, I strongly disagree that we should be recommending that an edit be made or approved which *just* makes that type of change, which is what this question is about.

Comment: Deleted a bunch of now-irrelevant comments. I'd already gone to sleep by the time you posted this answer, but I agree with Makyen's assessment that it doesn't change the dupe status. However, I do think this is a good answer with very good points. Furthermore, while I do agree with Makyen that we cannot in good conscience permit only a single A to be posted to a Q closed as opinion-based, I go one step further and say that closing a Q like this as opinion-based (esp. on a Meta site) is silly. So, I've reopened it and merged in your answer. Feel free to flag this comment once you've read it.

Comment: @mak *"I strongly disagree that we should be recommending that an edit be made or approved which **just** makes that type of change"* - Why? Now that I've updated this answer and provided rationale for why this change is an improvement (even if invisible), why would you reject this sort of improvement? What's the sort of improvement you would *not* reject? And what makes one improvement more accept-worthy than the other?

Comment: @IInspectable Even if you were right that code fences would be better, the potential gain from such an edit would never outweigh the disadvantages of an edit, amongst other things cluttering the active question page with posts which don't need additional attention and taking this attention away from other posts who deserve their spot on the active question list or causing extra work for the people doing reviews.

Comment: @sam I feel this is just voicing an (alarmingly accepted) cultural trend: We're constantly allowing technical debt to accrue when addressing it doesn't have any *immediate* benefit. Something we *will* have to deal with, at some point. Better sooner than later. Sure, edits aren't invisible, though at only 2000 reputation, a user's edits [will not contribute to any review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), so that's eventually a non-issue.

Comment: @IInspectable Most users don't have >2k rep and the queues are already often at their capacity limit. It would be better if editors would focus on necessary edits instead of only changing from one code markup to another.

Comment: @sam *"only changing from one code markup to another"* - That fails to appreciate that I'm not suggesting to go from one arbitrary representation to another arbitrary representation. I'm suggesting to go from a representation that's either not self-describing or out-of-spec to a representation that's conforming to CommonMark, and *fully self-contained*. We can probably agree that the benefits are real, but won't agree on the amount of "noise" admissible in getting there. That's fine, though, Meta is there to discuss these things after all.

Comment: @IInspectable "Something we will have to deal with, at some point" - what? Why? There's currently no indication that the space-indented variant will ever become unsupported. And if SO ever decides that they want to do away with that syntax, they could just write code which migrates the old posts by transforming the spaces-based syntax to the fence-based one (should be trivial if you have access to their current markdown parser). I see absolutely no reasons to stipulate mass edits of a perfectly valid format because you fear things that might happen in the future.

Comment: @l4m *"what?"* - I was referring to a culture where short-term economic goals inhibit addressing technical issues with long-term consequences. *"I see absolutely no reasons to stipulate mass edits"* - I wasn't recommending **mass** edits. I was making a point that the two alternatives we have for formatting code aren't actually equivalent in their features. If you are editing a contribution or reviewing one you now know how they are different, and can make an educated judgement call on whether to allow or reject that edit.

Comment: the two alternatives are not equivalent, but they both have their advantages and disadvantages. It depends on the post which one is easier to use. For example code fences are bothersome if the code itself already contains code fences. On needs to find another symbol not used in the post or experiment with an increasing number of backticks.

Comment: Also indention has the advantage that one can already apply it in one's code editor before copy&pasting it to SO and for most language the code will still run while adding extra characters like backticks would throw syntax errors.

Comment: @sam *"they both have their advantages"* - I don't see any advantages of indented code blocks. The one example you make up is quite fabricated, and it can *always* be resolved by switching to tilde characters or an appropriate amount of characters. But I'm not arguing whether a hypothetical edit should be simple anyway. *"indention has the advantage that one can already apply it in one's code editor"* - That's not an advantage. That's one way to deal with a disadvantage of indented code blocks. And it's glossing over the fact that you have to go back and undo your changes when done. I mean...

Comment: @IInspectable The example is not fabricated, that's daily business in the `rmarkdown` tag. Why bother with cumbersome workarounds when there is a more convenient way to mark the code in certain situations?

Comment: @cha You can use fenced code blocks inside lists. Those have to be indented following the normal rules of lists. Compared to indented code blocks you're still saving 4 horizontal space characters.

Comment: One debatable advantage of indents is it is what the code block control in the SO editor uses. I rarely use fences in my answers because it's very simple to highlight code and click a button

Comment: @cha That feature [has been requested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378924/1889329) already. Vote on it if you care enough.

Comment: But ... I don't care. Been doing it that way for years without negative repercussions

Comment: @sam It's unclear which standard R Markdown follows (or whether it follows any standard at all). Given that the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r-markdown/info) contains dead links to documentation, I wasn't able to see which variants of fenced code blocks it allows. Though, realistically, have you seen code blocks you weren't able to wrap inside `~~~~`?

Comment: Sure there are posts which have `~~~~` in their source

Comment: @sam Are you [sure](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1432389)?

Comment: @IInspectable your query is wrong, firstly the `Posts` table contains the rendered content and not the raw markdown, you want to check the `PostHistory` table instead, second `LIKE '~~~~'` would mean a post having literally only `~~~~` and nothing else, [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1432415/1759775/posts-using-tildes-for-code-blocks) is a more accurate query showing posts whose initial revision used tildes for code blocks.

Comment: Or if I misunderstood and you actually wanted posts that had tildes in the body not used for codeblocks [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1432419/1759781/) should be correct.

Comment: @abd That's still not accurate enough. It would have to look for a sequence of 4 tildes (`~~~~`) that are the first non-whitespace characters in each line.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, I'm sure :) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22%7E%7E%7E%7E%22

Comment: @sam Please find me a question that contains `~~~~` in a way that will not allow you to wrap it inside a fenced code block using `~~~~`. I've looked through several from the search query, and *none* were of that category. That's 955 questions, total, and I will be genuinely surprised if even 10% of them could not use fenced code blocks using `~~~~`. We're talking like 100 (max) questions out of, what, 21.4 million? The chances of finding a question that's somewhat harder (not even hard) to translate to fenced code blocks is on the order of winning any given national lottery.

Comment: Questions that do need special treatment are generally about Markdown itself (or its tooling). Like [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21584396/1889329), where every single code block can be fenced using one of the two available 3-character sequences. Now I might be going out on a limb here, but doing that might even turn out to be educational, *and* reach the same people that have an interest in this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the details and links about language heuristics not always working as expected. Also: language tag behind the fence backticks is optional, so people would still be free to omit it in obvious cases.

Comment: "The web-based editor has a fairly narrow fixed width." -- yes, I think SE made a pretty sub optimal editor in general. Even when reading non-code text, I personally wish they made the whole page span my whole monitor (it's not the "cool" design thing to do, for some reason news sites/blogs like to do this too). For editing (even viewing) code it's even worse. I think they shipped their first draft and then never got around to really iterating on it since, even though it's one of the first things a user interacts with. Maybe they consider it a "win" after the user signs up.

Comment: "a language indicator [were] redundant" -- definitely not true, there's no other way for posts that contain code from more than one language, or in a language not specified by the question (e.g., [XML configuration files plus C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53056968)). "Vertical separation" -- as a C/C++ programmer, this is doable, just put the name of the file immediately above the code block, like "header.h" (indented code) "implementation.c" (indented code). It's IMO a bit more readable than putting the file name in comments and having two code blocks right next to each other.

Comment: Fenced code blocks are against the "down" in [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (minimal markup), but with the new [weird syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) (and how the company implemented it), fenced code blocks are the cleanest way to deal with it (the HTML comment way is worse), often with [`<backtick> <backtick> <backtick> lang-none`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109). ...

Comment: cont' - Almost all [23,466,059 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) (and their answers) became broken overnight wrt. syntax highlighting by the change. *Missing* syntax highlighting would not have been a problem at all, but it is ***weird*** syntax highlighting.