# Can we please disfavor suggesting use of Code Fences in the formatting help panel?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

Honestly, I don't like code fences. New users to the site seem to have problems using them correctly, and they create unnecessary work to fix.

90% of the time that I'm on SO, I'm sitting in the new question queue looking for interesting questions and questions that need fixing up. I've noticed that since code fences started being recommended in the side panel when asking a question, new users have been trying, and failing to use them correctly.

Within a span of a few minutes, these questions were posted: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57381364/1) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381399/java-stream-distinct-is-not-working-as-expected) (+10k. Was deleted as I was posting this). I see many more than this. I could dig through my edit history if more examples are needed.

Why don't I like them? They're far too easy to mess up:

- People use the wrong quotes, which prevents codes fences from being recognized.
- People forget to close the fence, so any text after the code gets burried inside the code. I've seen multiple times where it seemed like the OP never asked a question, when in reality their question text was hidden at the bottom of code in a scroll box.
- The language tagging feature seems unnecessary, and is just another thing that we're expecting new users to get right. The tags on the question already (fairly accurately) pick the formatting to use. In an edge case where it picks the wrong language, a `<-- lang` element can be added, or a code fence could be used in those rare cases.
- If a new user messes up using a fence, it's more work to fix than if they did no formatting at all. If they mess up a fence in one of the ways above, I need to remove their erroneous formatting, *then* apply a fix.

What I'd like changed:

- Add mentions of the `{}` formatting button and how to use it (highlight code, click `{}` or ctrl+k; easy). Make indent formatting the primary suggestion at the top of the help panel.
- Make suggestions of code fences less prominent. Don't make them the main suggestion.
- Mention that fact that adding tags effects highlighting (although this is minor. I do think it falls under "formatting" though). The current panel says "add language identifier to highlight code", which makes it seem like that's how you add highlighting, even though there are other ways.

---

While I was writing this, I was thinking entirely about "non-guided" asking mode. I just checked the wizard however, and it gives the same advice when entering code. I think both areas should be changed.

Comment: Code fences are a more subtle way of adding code and save (at least me) from that bad CTRL + K code indentation. If users replace them with quotes then you can edit the question and in the summary, mention about the error they did. That's how one learns. It is prone to error. So what?

Comment: @weegee _"It is prone to error. So what?"_ That's what's bothering me a lot also, that's what.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, if something is prone to error, doesn't mean it should not be promoted. It should be promoted even more. So there's a correct use

Comment: Are the errors from code fences _worse_ than indentation errors? I know from past experience fixing broken indentation has not been a picnic either.

Comment: @Jon Four spaces are still the least error prone way to post code in markup. I've done a lot of edits already to fix all the misconsceptioned shite.

Comment: @Jon Just another silly [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381986/convert-python-dictionary-to-c-format)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Really? I've switched to code fences and it's pretty trivial to paste in code without futzing with indentation at all. Is the problem mostly using the wrong quotes and forgetting to close the fence? Or is there something I'm not seeing? (I would have liked to pre-fill code fences in [our template experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363051/ask-a-question-template-v1-experiment-results), by the way. But we didn't have that feature yet.)

Comment: @JonEricson I think they are. The forgetting to close the fence to me can lead to text being hidden. The same thing can happen with indentation, but in my experience the same error is much less common with indentation for whatever reason. And I find fixing indentation errors to be easier. I could be biased though as I'm mostly using the app, and highlighting + `{}` is more straightforward on mobile than needing to navigate to the backticks (2 extra clicks). It isn't major in either case, but minor things multiplied start to add up.

Comment: @Jon No, these are like a plague. It shouldn't be recommended.

Comment: If people disagree, then OK. I could be looking at it wrong. This isn't the hill I'm going to die on. Just thought I'd bring it up, as they annoy me.

Comment: @Jon It seems that most (newbie) people don't get the difference of backticks and single quotes nayways.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: It's worth discussing. As it happens, we've been looking at this exact bit of guidance this week. I think the problems you mention are valid. (I especially agree the advice should not emphasis adding a language for highlighting.) We're all on the same page about wanting to make it easier for users to insert code. The question is whether indentation is the right choice. (I'm unconvinced.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I wonder if a warning when someone enters `'''` would be a more expedient solution?

Comment: Don't let people submit questions where code fences aren't closed. Tada.

Comment: @JonEricson I could be favoring indentation mentally too because it's what I'm historically used to dealing with. I am stubborn like that. And detection of fence errors (wrong ticks and missing closing ticks) would address the problems I have with them.

Comment: @JonEricson However, I felt that this feature even lowered code formatting quality recently. I really hate it, and I even hat to fix that stuff with eedits.

Comment: another example of missing closing fence: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57265904/1 which is unfortunate because links and images are also broken because of this. Interestingly users seem to often combine indention and fences ...

Comment: Most users I've seen get the hang of code fences very fast, where as the indentation-based system results in all kinds of ugly formatting, or lack thereof. I vote in favor of keeping it, and adding warnings for incorrect formatting symbols instead. No matter what formatting you use though, you will find broken formatting.

Comment: @user36296: Yes. Using both at the same time indicates our guidance is confusing to say the least. I wonder if people are using the Ctrl-K (or related menu icon) feature and adding code fences as a result of the guidance.

Comment: @JonEricson Another possible source for confusion, e.g. in edits, is that many users only know of either fences or indention, but not both, so they think the other method is wrong and needs fixing (see for example the comment threat below https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8158/36296 ) If such an important change is introduced, it might be helpful to inform all users about it?

Comment: @JonEricson Another potential source of confusion is [how both ways are mentioned in the sidebar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387779/2751851).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please keep code fences prominent! In [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and a few other languages whitespace is part of syntax (opinions about this feature vary), and broken indentation will lead to broken code. Before we had code fences the only way to create code blocks was to indent everything by four spaces, which happens to be the standard indentation level in most python code. The fact that indentation was involved in code formatting meant that you could never be sure that a given indentation issue was there in the asker's original code, or if it's just an artifact of posting to SO. For the same reason we would discourage everyone from "fixing" code markdown on such questions, for fear of introducing new bugs or fixing bugs that should be there.

With code fences it's now possible to keep the asker's code intact, by surrounding their however-it-is-indented code with fences. This almost guarantees that no further indentation problems are introduced due to asking on Stack Overflow.