# Are code fences officially preferred yet? User found error message saying otherwise!

Tags: bug, code-formatting, error-message

I found [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75913449/how-do-i-fix-a-parsing-error-in-javascript) where the asker had been presented with an "error" message:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
> code. Please **indent all code by 4 spaces** using the code toolbar button
> or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?]
> toolbar icon.

[Emphasis mine.]

I thought that code fences were the preferred method of enclosing code nowadays.

Should the "error" message be updated?

---

Reference: [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark):

> Until now, you could do this to declare the language for an indented
> code block:
>
> ```
> <!-- language: python -->
>
>     def hello():
>         print("Hello, World");
> ```
>
> Moving forward, **this style is considered deprecated**.

Comment: "Are code fences official yet?" - yes, and have been for years. OP, in the question you linked to, said they used `<pre><code>`, which isn't the same thing. If their statement is correct, they also closed the tags in the wrong order, which could've contributed to the warning. Code fences aren't the problem here, and the error appears to be doing its job

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine If code fences are the preferred method, why does the "error" message say to indent by four spaces? That's what I'm asking about. (And I just added the "error-message" tag.)

Comment: Related, but from ~4 years ago and without a conclusive answer: [*What is the preferred method for formatting code?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387765/2751851). Around that time, I made [a report similar in spirit to yours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387779/2751851). Though the sidebar I asked about no longer exists, the issue lives on.

Comment: You were not clear with what part you were calling faulty. It's outdated, yes, but the error isn't faulty. Code fences are, AFAIK, not preferred. Both are supported, and only code  fences support explicit language definitions now, but that doesn't mean there's anything wrong with the advice. Space indents are one of the now two ways to format code, and neither is preferred above the other. The message should probably be updated to reflect that code fences are an option though

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine As [linked-to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) by rene in answer to the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423982/how-do-i-fix-a-parsing-error-in-javascript) in question, the four-space indent is deprecated, so it should no longer be promoted as correct formatting, as far as I understand.

Comment: Just because an error message says "You need to do X! You can accomplish it by following Y steps!" **does not imply** that other steps that also accomplish X are somehow invalid. As a general rule, across user interfaces, time and space. The error message is just trying to be helpful by facilitating the Xing.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Should an error message promote deprecated methods?

Comment: There does not seem to be any kind of consensus that either method is preferred nor deprecated.

Comment: @AndrewMorton No. The deprecation notice is specifically and exclusively for declaring code blocks with a specific language. Using `<!-- language: python -->` in front of a space block is deprecated while ```lang isn't. One specific use-case being deprecated doesn't mean space indented code blocks at large are deprecated.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Hmmm, I don't think that interpretation is in line with the spirit of the declaration.  Let's see what other input we get :)

Comment: See [CommonMark specification section 4.4: Indented code blocks](//spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#indented-code-blocks) and [CommonMark specification section 4.5: Fenced code blocks](//spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#fenced-code-blocks). Both are fully valid. Neither is officially "preferred". The *current* post editor has integrated functionality for formatting code blocks using indenting. The "Stacks Editor", which SE has been heavily pushing, even though it, still, has major issues and isn't on par as far with respect to features (e.g. no Stack Snippets), uses code fences, at least some of the time.

Comment: FWIW, the [Formatting Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) still prefers indentation over code fence.

Comment: @AndrewT. That same document may need updating as it still refers to the [`<blink>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink) tag which has long gone from being deprecated to unsupported (so young people may not understand the remark).